# issue servlet mapping servlet mapping url pattern

Tags: servlets

My requirement is to allow url with /endpoint/ & with an extension .json

something like this /endpoint/*.json but this pattern is not allowed in servlet-mapping but it gives invalid pattern exception.

The pattern /endpoint/*json doesn't give any exception but doesn't seems to work as expected.

What could be the solution to this.

Comment: u could use spring or struts for this

Comment: u mean to say in controller I should add @RequestMapping("/getResponse.json") & in web.xml <url-pattern>/endpoint/*</url-pattern>

Comment: yeah, you should try it,